# Laravel 5.2 datepicker

Tags: javascript, laravel, bootstrap-datepicker

For days, I'm trying to get Datepicker functionality in my web application (based on Laravel 5.2). Can't get it to work.

In the head section of my layout file I add:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
```

and at the bottom I have

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-JmvOoLtYsmqlsWxa7mDSLMwa6dZ9rrIdtrrVYRnDRH0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

In the view file I have

```
   <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
     <input type="text" class="form-control">
     <div class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
     </div>
   </div>
```

I'm seeing the date field but when I click on it, it simply tries to open the dateselector, but it appears empty (so no dates inside)

Suggestions welcome!

Note: screenshot here [image]

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: No error in console

Comment: Most probably an issue with missing styles then.

Comment: Provide a screen-shot of how the date selector looks like when you focus the input field.

Comment: I added the screenshot in the original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said above, it looks like you need to add bootstrap CSS to your app.

If you intend to use datepicker (or any other bootstrap elements) in more than 1 view then I would add it to your layout view, it will make life a lot easier than adding it to each file.

If you have added the files locally to your project to public/assets/css then call them with the below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}"/>  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css')}}"/>
```

OR

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add bootstrap.css as well. The styling of the elements in the calendar takes from that stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Include bootstrap styles and javascript files. they are required to use bootstrap-datepicker.

Comment: The rest of my app already has the bootstrap style so they are included for sure.

Comment: I have now manually added the css and js files to 'resources>css' and 'resources>js' and then run gulp. Didn't change anything.